# SpriteKit Vector graphics performance

Tags: ios, swift, vector, sprite-kit, sprite

For my SpriteKit game I am using a single pdf vector graphics for my SKSpriteNodes rather than many png sprites for all device resolutions for every entity in the game. the benefits of not having to worry too much about the graphics of the game have dramatically helped but my question is simple, would using vector graphics be a bad idea performance wise?

Comment: Use a PDF file?  What does Apple's SpriteKit documentation say about creating a sprite with an image file?

Comment: Yeah when I was researching about vector graphics in SpriteKit using pdf came up quite a lot and it works I guess but is that not good? I will have a look as well

Comment: I think you should use PNG.  But if PDF works for you, then I guess it doesn't matter.  I should mind my own business.  Sorry about that...

Comment: Oh no haha it is all good!! I am okay for any advice because I am new to SpriteKit and just making sure I am not creating any bad habits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Wait, you are NOT using a PDF as texture for the SKSpriteNode

Instead you are probably using a PDF into the Xcode Asset Catalog right?

[image]

In this case, first of all this is a really good idea and it does **NOT** impact the performance of your game.
Infact when you load a PDF image into the Xcode Assets (and you set the `Scale Factors` to `Single Vector`), you are **not** using the PDF into your app or game.

As soon as you compile the app, Xcode **automatically generates the PNG** versions for the several resolutions.

> E.g. if you game does support any device running iOS 9 then Xcode
>   automatically generates the 1x, 2x and 3x PNG (bitmap) images from your
>   original PDF (vector).

Another great benefit of this approach: if in the future Apple does release a device with a 4x pixel density, Xcode will likely be updated to support that and you'll just need to recompile your app to automatically generates the 4x images.

### Answer

So the answer to your question is: **NO**. The PDF image will not impact your game performance simply because the game is not using the PDF, it's using the PNG instead (even if you can't see it).

Comment: Ahhhh I see thank you so much!! That makes so much sense!! Great explanation too!!

Comment: @AtomProgrammer: good, please don't forget to accept the answer if it does solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry I thought I did